# JavaScript - 'this.form' returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, this, undefined

I am trying to change the functionality of a part of my website.
Currently, I have a Validate button that is outside of my table. Whenever the user clicks on that button, the Validation occurs.

However, I am changing that in a way that the Validate button will be removed and the functionality will be moved to a Link Button that resides inside the table.

Below is my code for this:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        //something else here
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right">
        <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="myGridView_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    // some control
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    // some control
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 3">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    // some control
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 4">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClientClick="return MyValidation__Submit(this.form)" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnValidate_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>    
<div style="margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;">
    <asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClientClick="return MyValidation__Submit(this.form)"  CommandArgument="Save" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnValidate_Click" />
</div>
```

And here is sample of the JavaScript block which does the validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyValidation__Submit(formName) {
        alert("Test   :" + formName);
        // do validations

        var joForm = document.getElementById(formName.id);

        for (var i = 0; i < joForm.elements.length; i++) {
            // do something
        }

        return true;
    }
 </script>
```

This works very well when the Validate button is clicked but not on the LinkButton.
To test it, I had to put the `alert("Test   :" + formName);` line. Whenever I fire the Validate button, the system alert returns a string value of "[object HTMLFormElement]" which I assume is okay considering that it functions the way I want it to. However, when I try to fire the Validate LinkButton which resides inside the table, the system alert returns "undefined" making the whole of my validation code useless.

Can someone please point out what i'm missing here? I'm guessing it has something to do with the hierarchy of the controls since that's the only thing that's changed.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is the furthest I can go but I still can't get to the form.
This one returns `HTMLDivElement`.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClientClick="return MyValidation__Submit(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnValidate_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Yes, you read that right. It has 5 `.parentNode`.

Comment: Can we see your validation code. Were you expecting the actual name of the form as the argument `formName`? If so, you'd want to do `MyValidation__Submit(this.form.name)` instead of simply `this.form`

Comment: please see my edit above. basically, I use the `formName` to get the ID. I can't really change the parameters of this Validation since it is an existing function and it might screw up other modules that uses this as well.

Comment: Is your problem with writing the ASP to generate the HTML you want (then show ask about that instead of the end result), or is it just with the way the generated HTML and JS interact (in which case, show us the generated HTML, not the ASP)?

Comment: `<asp:LinkButton` suggests some sort of insane `<a>` element wrapped with bundles of JavaScript to make it act like an `<input type="submit">`. Just use an `<input type="submit">` (and, optionally, apply CSS to make it look the way you want).

Comment: I am asking how i'll get my validation which is in JavaScript to work considering that using the button outside my GridView works while my LinkButton inside the GridView doesn't work even if they do have the same implementation.

Comment: It has something to do with `this.form`. It's giving me headache for the past two hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edit] accepted answer is last example

You say you're using jQuery, so if you've only got one form element on the page why not just do?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyValidation__Submit() {
        // do validations
        var joForm = $('form').eq(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < joForm.elements.length; i++) {
            // do something
        }
        return true;
    }
 </script>
```

even if you have more than one form you could do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyValidation__Submit(obj) {
        // do validations
        var joForm = $(obj).parents('form').eq(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < joForm.elements.length; i++) {
            // do something
        }
        return true;
    }
 </script>
```

and call it as

```
OnClientClick="return MyValidation__Submit(this)"
```

**Without jQuery** you can revert to `getElementsByTagName()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyValidation__Submit() {
        // do validations

        // getElementsByTagName("form") searches for any <form> elements on the page and returns an array of elements
        // the [0] then selects the first one in the array that was found
        // as long as you've only got one form on the page this should work
        var joForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < joForm.elements.length; i++) {
            // do something
        }
        return true;
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason either of these two doesn't work. I tried putting `alert(joForm);` after the `joForm` declaration but it doesn't fire. Also, everything else  below that doesn't fire. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to know without a more full example, but if you're using any recent browser then there are tools you can use to find out. In IE press F12 on your page and got to the Script tab and you should see any javascript errors there if you can't step through them in Visual Studio. Chrome and Firefox have similar developer tools.

Comment: yeah, i tried debugging on IE and it returns an error saying "Object expected" and points to this line `var joForm = $(obj).parents('form').eq(0);` I also tried the first solution and it points exactly the same error. What do you mean a more full example? :S

Comment: By the way if it's of any help these codes are in a user control (ascx) file. I don't know if it's got an impact on the `this.form`.

Comment: If the first one gives you that error, then that suggests you either don't have a form element on the page, or jQuery isn't loaded?

Comment: Try `var joForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];` in the first example instead

Comment: That's it!!!!!! That made it work! Thanks a lot!!!! If it's not too much of a hassle, can you give me an overview of how this code works? Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer with a final example and some comments for you

Answer (score 0):

My ASP knowledge is a bit rudimentary, but I believe it's because when you use "this.form" for your button, the scope of "this" is the document object. But when used for your LinkButton, the scope of "this" is the GridView.  If you're going to be moving the trigger item around, perhaps it'd be better to set the formName that you pass to the javascript function more explicitly.

Comment: `this` would refer to the button itself.

Comment: hi, exactly my thoughts but I don't really know how i'd climb up the hierarchy. I tried changing it to `OnClientClick="return JFFormScoreValidation__Submit(this.parentNode)"` which returns not the form but `[object HTMLTableCellElement]`. Any idea how  I can correct this? Thanks!